# Problem in Unity: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: unity-game-engine, indexoutofrangeexception

I always have the following problem when I execute the code in Unity:

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

The property Grid I set directly in the Unity editor with a value of 10 for x and y.

public class World : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Room[,] Dungeon { get; set; }
public Vector2 Grid;

private void Awake()
{
    Dungeon = new Room[(int)Grid.x, (int)Grid.y];
    StartCoroutine(GenerateFloor()); 
}

public IEnumerator GenerateFloor()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Grid.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Grid.y; y++)
        {
            Dungeon[x, y] = new Room 
            {
                RoomIndex = new Vector2(x, y) 
            };
        }
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    Vector2 exitLocation = new Vector2((int)Random.Range(0, Grid.x), (int)Random.Range(0, Grid.y));
    Dungeon[(int)exitLocation.x, (int)exitLocation.y].Exit = true;
    Dungeon[(int)exitLocation.x, (int)exitLocation.y].Empty = false; 
    Debug.Log("Exit is at: " + exitLocation); }}
```

I hope you can help me in this case

Comment: The error says non-negative or less. I think that means that it can't be equal to the size of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to see an error like this, without debugging the code. But in General,try to break public Vector2 Grid; 2 int variables and to use them,so do not need to be explicitly cast to an int, and your code will become significantly readable if you want x==y then we can make the test in Awake and fail to accidentally ask the wrong value. And Vector2 exitLocation can be replaced with Vector2Int or 2 variables.